# Treat multiple clauses in Elasticsearch query as distinct

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch query with a 'Should' clause of the following format. The intention is to search for multiple query strings with a single request:

```
[ 
    { match: { "name": { query: "Candied Apples" } } },
    { match: { "name": { query: "Canned Pears" } } } 
]
```

As per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-query-strings.html ES is combining these clauses, so a document named 'Canned Apples and Pears' is getting a higher score than 'Canned Pears', even though 'Canned Pears' is an exact match of one of the query strings. Is there a better way to structure my query so that each clause is evaluated separately?

To be clear, I would want a document with the name 'Canned Apples and Pears' to be returned as part of the search example above, but it should have a lower score than any documents named "Candied Apples" or "Canned Pears", because it does not match any of the search clauses exactly. This means a minimum_should_match value of 100% in not appropriate.

Full disclosure - I'm new to ES!

Answer (score 0):

One approach which seems to achieve the scoring structure I am looking for, is to combine "match_phrase" and "match" for each search term into a single query, e.g:

```
[ 
    {match_phrase: { 'name': { query: 'Candied Apples' } } },
    {match_phrase: { 'name': { query: 'Canned Pears' } } },
    {match: { 'name': { query: 'Candied Apples' } } },
    {match: { 'name': { query: 'Canned Pears' } } } 
]
```

This means that all full and partial matches are returned, but any successful phrase matches will have a higher score than the results of the 'match' clauses.

Please note that for this to work, the 'match_phrase' clauses must be listed first.